# Flutter/Dart - The getter 'path' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: path

Tags: flutter, dart, null, conditional-statements

I'm using a playerWidget based on `flutter_audio_recorder`. Though it works as required I get an annoying error message error upon compiles and hot restarts because the path is null at first. The path is null because no audio files have yet loaded. But once the `PageView.builder` which I'm using completes, the audio is then loaded so the error message has no effect on the actual operation. However the error message is becoming annoying. So I'd like to provide a default audio file from my server so the error will stop.

The error message says

```
  ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SpeakRecorder(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<SocialProvider>], state: SpeakRecorderState#5e63d):
The getter 'path' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: path
```

And the Widget which calls the error is;

```
child: PlayerWidget(url: _current.path),
```

I tried the following;

```
String defaultaudio = _current.path ?? 'http://example.com/ping.m4a';
```

But it doesn't resolve the path is null error.  Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error means that `_current` is `null` whatever it is. You can instead write `_current?.path ?? 'http://example.com/ping.m4a';`.

Comment: That did the trick! How can I can give you the credit? Can you answer the question formally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The getter 'path' was called on null.

This error means the the object for which you are writing `object.path` is `null`. You can use `?.` operator like this: `object?.something` which is equivalent to:

```dart
object!=null ? object.something : null
```

You can pair it with `??` operator which you are already doing. So you only have to change your statement to:

```dart
String defaultaudio = _current?.path ?? 'http://example.com/ping.m4a';
```